# Prior Art Sketches

Tags: us20060016456

In reference to the patent: [US20060016456](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060016456)

I am listing this invention as Prior Art, but I can not find the sketches for this invention. How can I obtain them, please?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no drawings present:
http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=2006016456A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=3&date=20060126&DB=worldwide.espacenet.com&locale=en_EP
Also in the Espacenet database I see none. Since the description does not refer to drawings I assume it was never intended to file any.